# HTML/PHP: How do I email a form using PHPMailer without getting a blank page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Original question:  HTML/PHP: How do I input checkboxes and radio buttons from a form into php, email said form, and redirect to a separate page?

Edit:  I have taken Drew's suggestion and rehosted it the website on a different web hosting service (byethost), but I am still getting an error when I hit submit.  When I click it, all I get is a blank page and I don't know why.  Can anyone help?  Here's a [link](http://danelerh.byethost17.com/character-creation/noble-cabalist.html) to the relevant page of the site.  Thank you.

I am working on a form where the user is creating a character for a game.  In this, I want it to email me the information for storage and reference.  The code is a bit lengthy, so here are some links:

[Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dzv08r3rlupx1i/noble-cabalist%20form.zip?dl=0)

<s>This HTML page will link from the user clicking links based on their character preferences, so some of the radio buttons are already filled in.  I also want to limit the number of checkboxes the user can select, hence the javascript at the bottom.  What I am looking to do is find a way to send the answers the user inputs to me.  The issue on this part is that I've seen answers that others gave to similar questions, but I haven't fully understood what it was they were doing because of how new I am to PHP.</s>
Edit:  I think I have this part working, but I can't confirm it since I still can't seem to find out why the email still won't send.

<s>The second part (that links to the first part) is that I don't know how to send the answers as an email.  I have tried, but so far I have failed to send anything.  (As you can tell in the PHP, the "to" and "from" are both to myself.  That's because whether or not they get a copy is optional.)

Edit: I have started trying PHPMailer, but I can't seem to find out why it won't send.  To be more specific, when it's hosted and I hit "submit", I get a "405 Not Allowed".  Here's a link to the relevant page of the site.</s>

<s>The final part is that I want it to link to another website when they hit "submit".  For right now, it just links to Google.  I can successfully link it when I'm not trying to send an email, but it doesn't work when I do try.</s>
Edit: This part isn't completely necessary.  It's just a preference that I can do without.

If I can get help on any of these problems, that would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) for the example you posted which does not support PHP (or any other server side language to run).  Apparently it also blocks POST requests because it doesn't make sense to use them since you can't run any (server side) code from a GitHub page.

You will need to set that `confirmation.php` script up on another server that allows you to run PHP code or test your project elsewhere.

GitHub Pages are for hosting static websites that only contain HTML, CSS, or JavaScript and will not let you have a form processor or run any PHP code.

I only briefly looked at the source of your form processor, and it may work perfectly fine, but you will need to run it on a webhost that supports PHP which GitHub pages does not.

Comment: That would explain it, then.  I guess I'll look for another place to host it.  Thank you for your help.